# Can't make the ui in gnome builder and cambalache

Tags: xml, gnome-builder

I don't know what I am doing wrong for the GtkGrid doesn't work.
[The ui that I made in Cambalache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnhAg.png)
[After run it in gnome builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP6KS.png)

I don't find any similar situation to help me. I don't know if the problem is in GtkGrid or with the versions.
The versions:

```
<requires lib="Adw" version="1.0"/>
  <requires lib="gtk" version="4.0"/>
  <requires lib="gio" version="2.0"/>
  <requires lib="libadwaita" version="1.4"/>
```